# Repair or Plug a rusted cleanout

Tags: plumbing, repair, cleanout

I am selling a house, and am just about ready to put it on the market.  Just yesterday I noticed the cleanout to the sewage line is rusted through just below the cap.

Is there some way to repair this?  Extend it somehow and recap?  Plug it?

The last thing I want to do is start digging in concrete.

I assume I can't leave it as is?

[image]

Comment: You can get an expanding rubber plug for that.  Go to a plumbing supply store (not a big box store).

Comment: Like this: https://m.grainger.com/mobile/product/1VNG7?cm_mmc=PPC:+Google+PLA&cm_mmc=PPC:+Google+PLA?campaignid=175663197&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!50916758397!!!g!!&ef_id=WlgHVgAAAMYfkAx7:20180416221500:s

Comment: Yes, you need to fix by large hammer and cold chisel to remove that old plug and use an expanding plug as linked by @Tyson

Comment: Once you get the old plug out, discard it (recycle) you can use a plastic plug (ABS, PVC, polypropylene) which screws in the threads. Smear the threads with silicone grease and it will seal even if it will go in only one thread deep. Alternatively there are metal (brass or cast iron) plugs which have a band of lead around where the threads would be. This type of plug is pressed in with the tap of a heavy hammer and is used where the threads in the fitting are too corroded away to take any screwed in cap. I think they are code compliant.